# Can't position elements on top of each other - CSS Bootstrap ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

The text should be in white badge with text center . I use gatsby StaticImages by the way....

[image]

Code..

```
<div class="row mx-4"  style={{ position:'relative' }}>

                        <StaticImage style={{ position:'absolute',  filter: 'brightness(100%)' }} src="../images/scrollg.png"  alt="tatil" placeholder="tracedSVG" />
                        
                        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end pt-4 pe-4"  >
                             <StaticImage  src="../images/badge.svg"  alt="tatil" placeholder="tracedSVG" />
                         
                             <div style={{ position:'absolute'}}>   <p  className="text-center">200€’dan başlayan fiyatlarla</p></div>
                    
                       </div>
                       
                        <div className="row mx-5 scrollg" style={{ position:'absolute' , height:'400px'}}>
                                <div className="col-12 my-auto">
                                <h4 className="fw-bold text-white">Roma’yı Keşfetme Mevsimi</h4><br />
                                <p className="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 scrollg">Haydi, siz de Tatilbudur’un uygun fiyatlı yurt dışı turlarını incelemeye başlayın, yurt dışında daha fazla yeni yerler keşfetmenin keyfine varın!</p>
                                <button class=" px-3 py-1 scrollg-button rounded-pill  "> Fırsatları Gör</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: please post a minimal editable example

Answer (score 0):

The text here needs to be positioned absolutely and *relative* to the parent div element within which the text and the image are. So you'll have to add `position-relative` class to the parent.

To center the text vertically, you can add equal distance on the `top` and `bottom`.

To make sure the text is within the white badge, you can add some fixed `width` to th text div.

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-end pt-4 pe-4 position-relative">
     <StaticImage  src="../images/badge.svg"  alt="tatil" placeholder="tracedSVG" />
     // I've added 100px width as an example.                    
     <div style={{ position:'absolute', top: '25%', bottom: '25%', width: '100px'}}>   
         <p  className="text-center">200€’dan başlayan fiyatlarla</p>
    </div>                
 </div>
```